# What Rule generates the sequence $8,8,10,12,12,14,16,16$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

What is the rule that generates the following sequence? I can not solve it.

```
                8 8 10 12 12 14 16 16
```

For example: 1 3 5 7 9 11 Rule: $n+2$

Comment: Compare with the highly-downvoted http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467202/rule-of-this-number-sequence

Comment: Which of the [three sequences](http://oeis.org/search?go=Search&q=8%2C8%2C10%2C12%2C12%2C14%2C16%2C16) do you mean?

Answer (score 9):

The simplest answer is $$a_n = 8 + 2 \left\lfloor \frac{2n}{3} \right\rfloor$$ with $n$ start at $0$.
By trial and error, a more complicated one is
$$a_n = \frac13(4n+22)+ \frac{4}{\sqrt{27}}\cos(\frac{4 n + 1}{6}\pi)\tag{*1}$$
If one inspect carefully about this expression, one can see that it is a linear combination of 4 terms:

$$n,\;\;1,\;\;e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3} n}\;\text{ and }\;e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3} n}$$
The last 3 terms are powers of the cubic roots of unity. This means these
parts satisfy a recurrence relation of the from $p_{n+3} - p_{n} = 0$. The
$n$ term satisfies a recurrence relation of the form $q_{n+2} - 2 q_{n+1} + q_{n} = 0$. Combine these, we see $a_n$ satisfies a $4^{th}$ order recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+4} - a_{n+3} - a_{n+1} + a_{n} = 0$$

We can use these and the initial values: $a_0 = 8, a_1 = 8, a_2 = 10$ and $a_3 = 12$
as a recursive "definition" of all $a_n$. Alternatively, one can skip the part on $n$
term and use the inhomogeneous $3^{rd}$ order recurrence relation:

$$a_{n+3} - a_{n} = 4\tag{*2}$$

with the initial values for $a_0, a_1, a_2$ as definition of the recurrence relation.

Of course, this is going the tortuous route.  One can start with the obvious relation
$(*2)$, working backwards and get the explicit answer $(*1)$.

Comment: The question is not to find a procedure $n\mapsto a(n)$ (or similar) but $a(n)\mapsto a(n+1)$ (or similar).

Comment: (+1) I think this answer is fine. Calculating $a(n+1)-a(n)$ can be left as an exercise to the reader. ;)

Comment: When I posted my first comment the post stopped right after (*1). The added part indeed deals with the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like repeated (add 0, add 2, add 2)

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_{n+3} = 4+a_n$ and $a_1 = 8$, $a_2 = 8$, and $a_3 = 10$.

Comment: I mean, after all, you have three arithmetic sequences living in your original sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the $n$th term is $$-48 + \frac{3034}{21} n - \frac{2853}{20} n^2 + \frac{8477}{120}n^3 - \frac{153}{8}n^4 + \frac{23}{8}n^5 - \frac{9}{40}n^6 + \frac{1}{140}n^7.$$

To be less facetious: there are infinitely many rules that could generate this sequence. Unless you have more information about the process that generated it, you have no way of knowing which rule (if any!) it came from.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to find and get any ideas of the general term. [Here](http://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C8%2C10%2C12%2C12%2C14%2C16%2C16&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Helpful link, Babak +

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the $n$th term is $\frac43n+\frac{16}3+\frac43\,\mathbf 1_{n=1\bmod{3}}+\frac23\,\mathbf 1_{n=0\bmod{3}}$...

> Keep the **three** last values $x$, $y$ and $z$ of the sequence:
>
> - If $z=x+2$, set $t=z+2$.
> - If $z=x+4$, set $t=z$.
> - Replace $(x,y,z)$ by $(y,z,t)$.
> - Iterate.
>
> Initialize suitably.

Or, equivalently:

> Keep the three last values $x$, $y$ and $z$ of the sequence:
>
> - Set $t=x+4$.
> - Replace $(x,y,z)$ by $(y,z,t)$.
> - Iterate.
>
> Initialize suitably.

Comment: (+1) The first one uses the peculiarities of the sequence more, while the second one would hold for any sequence satisfying $a_{n+3}=a_n+4.$ Both are closer to getting from each term to the next as in the OP's example of 1,3,5 generated by $x\to x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of Did's answer: Keep the last *two* terms $x,y$. If $x=y$ then the next term is $z=x+2$. If $x \neq y,$ then if $x$ is divisible by 4, put $z=x+4$, and if $x$ is not divisible by $4$ put $z=x+2.$ Update $(x,y)$ to $(y,z)$ and iterate. [Initial values $8,8$]

Comment: Hmmm... so, being stupid forces one to keep 3 terms while knowing divisibility by 4 allows one to keep only 2 terms. Nice. (Since 1 term cannot suffice, this might be optimal.)

Comment: @Did -- Yes, I know of no property which a given single term could have, on which a choice whether to increase it by 2 or keep it the same for the next term could be based.

Comment: It is impossible! Since one 8 produces something (here, an 8) and another 8 produces something else (here, a 10). Or, one knows the time and can make decisions based on this knowledge... which seems out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @Did -- If one is willing to be off by a unit shift: Look at a single term. If it is divisible by 4 then put that term down again and go to the above "last two term" version, otherwise add 2 for the next term and again go to the "last two term" version. This is a bit of a fudge, and my previous comment should have had an icon like ;) after it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=n\pmod 3$ and $\beta=(n-1)\mod 3$ with $0\leq\alpha,\beta\lt 3$
then,

$a_n=a_{n-1}+2(1-(1-\delta(\alpha))(1-\delta(\beta)))$ where $\delta $ is dirac-delta function.